# I can't have remote desktop connection to server 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, remote-desktop

I've got a server running windows 2008r2 and I can remote from a pc running xp to it finely.But when I wanna  have remote connection from my pc running windows 7 ,it says

**remote computer could not find the remote computer .this can happen if the computer is not yet registered with the session broker .**

But I enter the name correctly and there is no problem with the connection by windows XP.
I added the user to remote access group.and I've added this computer to session broker group in server 2008.but it wasn't useful.what's the solution?

thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to provide more detail on your configuration. The Session Broker isn't a required component. The fact that you've mentioned it in your question leads me to believe that there's more to this question then you've presented.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Win 7 computer configured for Network level authentication in RDP properties. Disable it, turn off SSL, make it encryption level "RDP Client compatible" and try again.

Comment: iis is not instslled in my windows 7